# How to count the total amount of list correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to write an accounting book and got struggled with total amount counting, it can be count after the list print out but the number is incorrect. I tried to do it with `+` to count for total amount, but is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os

def read_file(filename):
    items = []
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'your product,your price' in line:
                continue
            #product,price = line.strip().split(',')
            #item.append([product, price])
        else:
            print("list>>> ----v")
        return item

def user_input(item):
    while True:
        product = input("\nitem:")
        if product == 'q':
            break
        price = input("\nprice:")
        price = int(price)
        item.append([product, price])
    return item

def print_file(item):
    for price in item:
        print(price[0], 'is: ', price[1])
        
        #total amount
        count = price[1]
        total_count = count + count
        num = (f"you spend total {total_count}")
    
        print(num)

def write_file(filename, item):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('your product,your price\n')
        for price in item:
            f.write(price[0] + ':' + str(price[1]) + '\n')

def main():
    filename = 'list.text'
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("File Found")
        file = read_file(filename)

    else:
        print("Wlecome")
    item = []

    item = user_input(item)
    print_file(item)
    write_file('list.txt', item)

main()
```

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `diamond-problem` which is one of tags you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small naming error when adding the counts, try this:

```py
def print_file(item):
    total_count = 0
    for price in item:
        print(price[0], 'is: ', price[1])
        
        #total amount
        count = price[1]
        total_count += count
     num = (f"you spend total {total_count}")
    
     print(num)
```

Comment: total_count must also be initialized. I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: you're right, I overlooked that

Comment: Which error did they make?

Comment: they had this line `total_count = count + count` instead of `total_count = total_count + count` which i abbreviated in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
def print_file(item):
    total = 0
    for price in item:
        print(price[0], 'is: ', price[1])
        total += price[1]
    num = (f"you spend total {total_count}")

    print(num)
```

or simply

```
def print_file(item):
    total = sum([price[1] for price in item])
    print(f"you spend total {total}")
```